# Encode/Decode JSON object for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I have an array **@gtaglist** created with Ruby that has been converted to a JSON object using **@gtaglist.to_json** giving

```
{"id":28,"name":"Rome Catacombs Tour"},{"id":31,"name":"Baroque Churches Tour"},{"id":27,"name":"Borghese Gallery Tour"}
```

I am substituting the value of the Ruby JSON object i.e `#{@gtaglist}` into a string in a Javascript tag statement and obtaining the following

```
gtag('event', 'view_item_list', {
    "items": {&quot;id&quot;:28,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Rome Catacombs Tour&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:31,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Baroque Churches Tour&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:36,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sts Peter &amp; Paul Tour&quot;}
    });
```

How do I replace the **`&quot;`** with "

Using Ruby 2.4.3, Sinatra and Slim

Comment: How are you getting the Ruby string into the `<script>` tag? [Is this what you're looking for?](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim#Output_without_HTML_escaping___)

Comment: post more details of your code

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @rael-gugelmin-cunha on 
[ruby inside javascript block [slim template]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794403/ruby-inside-javascript-block-slim-template)

Use double curly braces i.e `#{{@gtaglist}}` instead of `#{@gtaglist}`