# How can I conditionally include some Javascript in an html.slim file, as part of a larger Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I want my page to render some Javascript, conditional on a variable from the Rails environment. I must have everything in this one file, because of other build tooling constraints.

Eseentially I am trying to get this working:

```
= javascript:
     console.log('My javascript goes in this area....');
     <% if myCondition %>
          console.log('Render the JS in here is myCondition is true')
     <%end>
```

However, when I try this, I get errors that `<` is not a valid character.

Comment: Is it possible to simply do the check outside of the current `= javascript:` tag? And if that condition is true create a new block of javascript to be injected into the page

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia can you explain how to do that? I'm really fresh at this

Comment: @chumakoff's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58244019/8148483)

Answer (score 2):

```
 javascript:
   console.log('My javascript goes in this area....');

 - if myCondition
   javascript:
      console.log('Render the JS in here is myCondition is true')
```

Also, this question might be useful: [ruby inside javascript block [slim template]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794403/ruby-inside-javascript-block-slim-template)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `<% ... %>` in your javascript

If you want to use rails data, try e.i

`var form_id = "form"+ #{{@product.id.to_json}};`

Another way, you should be use ajax( it was mean your_action.js.slim ), see i.e bellow

> create.js.slim

```
- if @product.errors.present?
  | toastr["error"]("#{@product.errors.full_messages[0]}");
- else
  | toastr["success"]("Created successfully!");
```